# Set CardView height programmatically

Tags: android

I am new to Android dev and I'm having trouble trying to set the min height of a `it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView` programmatically. I create a new instance of a CardView and set all the xml elements in code, but it does not affect the cardView. I do not inflate the cardview from xml.

```
CardView catCard = new CardView(getActivity());

    catCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.green(0));

    catCard.setMinimumHeight(10);
    catCard.setBottom(0);
    catCard.setExpanded(false);
```

Comment: Is your view added to any view hierarchy or layout? The size of a view depends on its layout. Also, just to be sure I understand your question, have you indeed managed to set the height successfully when inflating from XML, and you want to know how to do it from code, or did you fail to set the height on this view also when inflating from XML?

Comment: I add the CardView into the LinearLayout and it works with all relevant data, but it does the methods used above do not affect the card at all. I have not been able to set the height as I am not inflating the view from xml but rather creating a new card and adding it to the xml file that is being inflated.

Answer (score 16):

CardView extends FrameLayout so you should be able to set LayoutParams. Try something like this :

```
 CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)
            catCard.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 10;
```

, dont forget that setting Width is also required. 
Or create new LayoutParams like this (not tested) :

```
CardView catCard = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
// sets width to wrap content and height to 10 dp ->
catCard.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(
     CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10));

catCard.setMinimumHeight(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have tried using this already but I get an error. Probably because I only set the height. Will try width and height. What do you mean by "create new LayoutParams"?

Comment: I editet my answer, hope it helps. You might want to try to create new LayoutParams first and then set the height with the above code CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams)
            catCard.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 10;

Answer (score 9):

```
myCardView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20));
```

it depends that your cardview is a child of which layout, in this case it is under Relative Layout

Answer (score 1):

My Solution with margin and it worked perfectly with me
 `val resources = context.resources // get resources from context
val width: Int = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 3      //get width 
val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()       //set margin
val layoutParams = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
layoutParams.marginStart = px
layoutParams.marginEnd = px
cardView.layoutParams = layoutParams`