# How to set the cardview height programmatically?

Tags: android, layoutparams, cardview

I am new in android development and I have searched this question, but not getting any solution.I want to ask how to make the `cardview` with `recyclerview` divide into three pieces in one screen?

[image: example]

this is my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code I try in Activity

```
View rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    double height =rootLayout.getLayoutParams().height/3.0;
    CardView card= (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
    CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams= (CardView.LayoutParams) card.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height=(int)height;
    layoutParams.width=MATCH_PARENT;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760418/set-cardview-height-programmatically

Comment: Define cardview hight like android:layout_height =wrap_content and set minimum android:minWidth="250dp".

Comment: Try like this implement



CardView card= (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
// Set the CardView layoutParams
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        (int)height;
                );
                card.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: make the cardview with recyclerview divide into three pieces in one screen? can you give snapshot what you want to make

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set CardView height programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760418/set-cardview-height-programmatically)

Comment: ok i will try it! thanks for answering me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try getting height of window and divide it by 3,

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels/3;
CardView card= (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) card.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height= height;
layoutParams.width=MATCH_PARENT;
card.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: I try to put the code into oncreate ,below setContentView(). I got the "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.support.v7.widget.CardView.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference"

Comment: instead of using CardView.LayoutParams use the LayoutParams.LayoutParams

Comment: fail java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: @dcarl661 use `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

Just as @V-rund suggested
Get the Screen/Window height and divide it by 3 using,

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels/3;
CardView card = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card);
```

but instead of using `CardView.LayoutParams` use the `LayoutParams` for the parent layout of your CardView which in your case will be a `LinearLayout`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
card.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = height;
layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
card.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I hope this helps solve your problem.